# How do you automatically render multiple frames of an animation as images, crop them, place them into position, and output a single image?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I'm a newbie to Blender's compositor, so I don't know if this is possible or how to do it.

I want to be able to automate the process of combining multiple animation frame renders into a single image for a character turntable collage, whereby the front, front angle, side, back angle, and back renders are side-by-side as a single image. Typically, I use an external image editing program to load all the the images into a single canvas, crop them, position them, and then export the combined image. Being able to automate this process in Blender would be more efficient and accurate.

The reason I do this is to quickly compare tweaks I've made to a character between major changes as I work on it by switching between composited images using an external image viewer.

I have a single camera pointed at the character and it is parented to an empty. This empty rotates around the character for five frames for each view angle stated above. I render out the animation, and so on.

Comment: I think this could work, but give me a minute to try it (and some time to get that minute lol). In the meantime, I recommend you look into the compositor yourself. You might figure out how to do this with file inputs and overlay.

Comment: I think the fastest way to use Blender to generate the composited image is to actually import the four frames into the VSE as 4 tracks one above the other; set the blend of each to _Over Drop_, the scale of each to .5 and the position to offset them.  Render that and you get a 2x2 'split screen'.  If you're willing to do the whole thing using two blend files it would be pretty easy

Comment: Appreciate the responses. Looks like a hacky solution was linked by a moderator (I'm assuming?) which uses separate scenes and a relatively simple node setup.